# How do I use plink on a MacBook Air?

Tags: bioinformatics

I'm a high school kid who's clueless about computing. I need to use PLINK on my MacBook for a bioinformatics project but I'm not sure how to even run it after downloading it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Mac with an intel processor?

Comment: @FatemehSangin Yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, you have to have jre or jdk installed. You can download jdk 8 (my preferred one) from [the link](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8). Just select the MacOS tab, and proceed.
- Once downloaded, double-click to install.
- Then, you have to download the application zip ([here](https://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/download.shtml)).
- Extract it.
- Double click on the gPLINK.jar in the extracted folder. If you faced an error, do the following: Open System Preferences> navigate to Security & Privacy icon > click on the lock icon below and enter password if required >on General tab, allow the program to be run.
- Now the program must be launched successfully. You can move the .jar file to a desirable location, so that you will not forget where it was located.

Comment: thanks for your help! i tried to give you a vote but my reputation is too low :(

Comment: It seems natural to assume the OP is after the command line version, not the GUI.

Comment: @user438383 Sorry, I didn't get you.